# Significance value in Hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

A builder claims that heat pumps are installed in $70\%$ of all homes being constructed today in Chennai. Would you agree with this claim if a random survey of new homes in this city showed that $8$ out of $15$ had heat pumps installed? Use a $10\%$ level of significance.

Here the null hypothesis(H$_0$) is $p = 0.7$ and alternative hypothesis(H$_A$) : $p \neq 0.7$. So, it is a both-ended test.

I want to compute the value of the type-1 error using the definition P ($A^c$ | $H_0$ is true), where A is the acceptance set, but I cannot formulate it correctly. How do we define the acceptance set?

I have completed the following two steps.

$\bullet$ Reject $H_0$ if $\big|T-10.5\big| > c$.

$\bullet$ P($A^c$ | $H_0$ is true ) = $\text{P} (T > c+10.5 \,\, \text{or} \,\, T < 10.5-c \,\, | \,\, p = 0.7 \,)= \text{P} (T > c+10.5 \,\,| \,\, p =0.7) + P(\,\, T < 10.5-c \,\, | \,\, p = 0.7 \,)$.

The above step is creating confusion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your work, where does $10.5$ come from?

Comment: @angryavian I have multiplied 10 with 0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a two-sided test that controls the Type I error, the critical values for a sample size of $n = 15$ are integers $L$ and $U$ such that $$\Pr[X \le L \mid H_0] \le \alpha/2, \quad \Pr[X \ge U \mid H_0] \le \alpha/2,$$
where $\alpha = 0.10$ is the overall significance level of the test, and $$X \mid H_0 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 15, p = 0.7)$$ is the random number of homes with heat pumps installed in a sample of $15$ homes surveyed.

Thus we want to find the largest such $L$ and smallest such $U$.  To this end, we calculate the cumulative distribution of $X$ under the null hypothesis:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X = 0 \mid H_0] &\approx 1.43489 \times 10^{-8} \\
\Pr[X \le 1 \mid H_0] &\approx 5.16561 \times 10^{-7} \\
\Pr[X \le 2 \mid H_0] &\approx 8.71935 \times 10^{-6} \\
\Pr[X \le 3 \mid H_0] &\approx 9.16587 \times 10^{-5} \\
\Pr[X \le 4 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.000672234 \\
\Pr[X \le 5 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.00365252 \\
\Pr[X \le 6 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.0152425 \\
\Pr[X \le 7 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.0500125.
\end{align}$$
We stop at $X \le 7$ because this is the first value that exceeds $\alpha/2 = 0.05$.  So the largest $L$ we can choose is $L = 6$, even though $L = 7$ is just barely above $\alpha/2$.

We perform the same process to locate $U$:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X = 15 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.00474756 \\
\Pr[X \ge 14 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.0352676 \\
\Pr[X \ge 13 \mid H_0] &\approx 0.126828.
\end{align}$$
Here we stop much sooner and obtain $U = 14$.  Thus the rejection region is
$$X \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 6\} \cup \{14, 15\}.$$
This region has a cumulative Type I error probability of $0.0152425 + 0.0352676 \approx 0.0505101$, which is not the full $0.10$ that we were allowed to "spend."  This is due to the fact that the sample size is small and the number of homes must be a nonnegative integer, so the test statistic has a discrete distribution.  Even if we allowed some of the overall significance level to be slightly unevenly distributed between the two tails of the test and included $X = 7$ in our rejection region, the Type I error would still fall short of what we could allocate.

Comment: It is perhaps worth remarking that if we had a (significantly) larger sample size, we could approximate the appropriate binomial distribution with a normal distribution, and this has the benefit of being symmetric about the mean and with the cutoffs for the most common significance levels being well known.  So, ironically, the computation is much more difficult because the small sample size forces you to actually compute the exact values and take the asymmetry of the distribution seriously.